# malloc a "member" of struct v.s. whole struct when struct is quite simple

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, malloc

I have searched on this site the topics about `malloc` on structs. However, I have a slightly problem. Is that `malloc` on the element of a struct different from `malloc` on the whole struct, especially when that struct is quite simple, that is, only a member that is exactly what we all want to allocate? To be clear, see the code corresponding to `student` and `student2` structs below.

```
struct student {
    int* majorScore;
};

struct student2 {
    int majorScore[3];
};


int main()
{
    struct student john;
    john.majorScore = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    john.majorScore[0] = 50;
    john.majorScore[1] = 27;
    john.majorScore[2] = 56;
 
    struct student2* amy= (struct student2*)malloc(sizeof(struct student2));
    amy->majorScore[0] = 50;
    amy->majorScore[1] = 27;
    amy->majorScore[2] = 56;


    return 0;
}
```

Are they different in memory level? If yes, what is the difference? If no, which is perhaps better in terms of a good programming style?

Comment: `malloc` on a stuct will only allocate the size of the struct itself, not the size of dynamic data pointed to by pointers within the struct.

Comment: You are not comparing like with like. For `john` you allocate the array within a local `struct`. For `amy` you allocate one `struct` on the heap with a fixed array. Which is better? If you don't know how many scores there are at compile time, they can't have a fixed array.

Comment: Are they different in memory level? Well you have provided two different struct definitions, so in that regard they are different. They are the same in that the dynamically allocated data will live somewhere in the `.heap` section of memory. Which is better in terms of good programming style? Debatable and dependent on your use cases. I would argue a `majorScore` array of size 3 isn't realistic for real-world scenarios, but if it suites your needs then it's fine to use this method.

Comment: `student2` contains a 3-elements array of `int`. `student` contains an `int` pointer. Those are two very different things.

Comment: The array option is clearer. Especially if you replace `3` with a well-named constant (`#define N_GRADES 3` for a not particularly well chosen name)

Comment: Hmm.. let me think about it. I also want to know are they consume the same memory size in heap (if we do want to fix the `int` array number as `3`, and won't change it latter)?

Comment: They are not required to if that's what you are asking. They very well could, depends on the implementation of the allocator.

Comment: Why don't you just find out for yourself by printing the `sizeof` value that you `malloc`? `sizeof(struct student2)` and `sizeof(int)*3`. They will also take up some stack memory as well, minimally to store a pointer. But optimizations at this level are negligible since both structs are very simple.

Comment: `sizeof(int)*3` is exactly how much memory you allocate from the heap for `student`. Assigning scores to the struct's array does not change how much memory it uses.

Comment: One stores exactly three integers and the other stores a pointer (which can point at 3 integers or 300 integers or 300000000 integers or 0 integers). Looks pretty much different to me.

Comment: I see. So the two structs are different in stack (due to their different definitions), but they consume the same amounts of memory in heap (both 12bytes).

Comment: In this particular implementation, yes.

Comment: @Eric `amy` isn't on the stack - it was allocated, but `john` is - it is a locally defined variable. However `john.majorScore` will point to memory allocated on the heap.

Comment: don't cast `malloc()` !

Comment: @tstanisl I have noticed such warning when searching on this site; however, without such casting my Visual Studio would not let the compilation be passed. Maybe because of I was written the code in an `.cpp` (rather than `.c`) file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you dynamically allocate one struct, but not the other. So you're comparing apples to oranges.

---

Statically-allocated structs:

```c
struct student john;
john.majorScore = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
john.majorScore[0] = 50;
john.majorScore[1] = 27;
john.majorScore[2] = 56;

struct student2 amy;
amy.majorScore[0] = 50;
amy.majorScore[1] = 27;
amy.majorScore[2] = 56;
```

```
struct student john
+------------+----------+      +----------+
| majorScore |         ------->|       50 |
+------------+----------+      +----------+
| [padding]  |          |      |       27 |
+------------+----------+      +----------+
                               |       56 |
                               +----------+

struct student2 amy
+------------+----------+
| majorScore |       50 |
|            +----------+
|            |       27 |
|            +----------+
|            |       56 |
+------------+----------+
| [padding]  |          |
+------------+----------+
```

`struct student` uses more memory because it has an extra value (the pointer), and it has the overhead of two memory blocks instead of one.

`struct student2` always has memory for exactly three scores, even if you need fewer. And it can't possibly accommodate more than 3.

---

Dynamically-allocated structs:

```c
struct student *john = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
john->majorScore = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
john->majorScore[0] = 50;
john->majorScore[1] = 27;
john->majorScore[2] = 56;

struct student2 *amy = malloc(sizeof(struct student2));
amy->majorScore[0] = 50;
amy->majorScore[1] = 27;
amy->majorScore[2] = 56;
```

```
struct student *john
+----------+      +------------+----------+      +----------+
|         ------->| majorScore |         ------->|       50 |
+----------+      +------------+----------+      +----------+
                  | [padding]  |          |      |       27 |
                  +------------+----------+      +----------+
                                                 |       56 |
                                                 +----------+

struct student2 *amy
+----------+      +------------+----------+
|         ------->| majorScore |       50 |
+----------+      |            +----------+
                  |            |       27 |
                  |            +----------+
                  |            |       56 |
                  +------------+----------+
                  | [padding]  |          |
                  +------------+----------+
```

Same analysis as above.

Comment: Wonderful diagrams for illustrating the data storage

Comment: don't forget that implementations of `malloc()` add non-trivial amount of data **before** the returned pointer. Moreover, usually the minimal allocated block is 32 bytes.

Comment: Thank you all very much. It is hard to select a best accepted answer, yours and h0r53's are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is malloc on a struct simple? Sure, it certainly is. Although you don't need malloc whatsoever for your `struct student2` definition, and I'd argue that just using the struct directly and avoiding `malloc` is MUCH simpler. It's important to note that `malloc` on a struct will only allocate the size of the struct itself, not the size of dynamic data pointed to by pointers within the struct. What you are comparing is two different structs with very different implementations, so it isn't really fair to say "which one is better" because it largely depends on your actual use cases.

For clarity, let's say you did `struct student* john = malloc(sizeof(struct student))`. If you allocate storage for a struct like this, you still need to allocate memory for `majorScore` since it the initial `malloc` only allocates room for the `int *` and nothing past that. As you can see, that complicates things even more.

So the conclusion is, in general you only want to use `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation in circumstances where you may not know the size of data at compile time. There is no reason to introduce complexity (and likely bugs/leaks) through `malloc` in the examples you have provided. The utility of using `malloc` in your example for `struct student` is that `majorScore` can be an array of any size, not just 3 as in the `struct student2` definition.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!